# is there any dependency manager for Racket?

Tags: racket

Like `npm` for node, we use `package.json` to solve dependencies.

I tried `raco pkg`, it seems to be just a way to dev/pub packages instead of solving external dependencies.

Comment: `raco pkg` reads `info.rkt` which can specify dependencies. I'm not sure what you mean by "external dependencies". Can you clarify?

Comment: @SoraweePorncharoenwase  it points to packages that aren’t included with the standard Racket distribution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I described above, `info.rkt` in Racket acts like `package.json` in JavaScript, and `raco pkg install` will read the dependencies specified in `info.rkt` and recursively install these dependencies.

For instance, here's the Pollen project's [`info.rkt`](https://github.com/mbutterick/pollen/blob/master/info.rkt). You can see that it specifies `txexpr` which is another package as a dependency. Therefore, when you `raco pkg install pollen`, it will ask you if you want to install `txexpr` too. You can also invoke `raco pkg install --auto pollen` which will install dependencies automatically without asking any question.

Note that these packages are registered with https://pkg.racket-lang.org/ which is an equivalent of https://www.npmjs.com/ in JS.

You can read the documentation of `info.rkt` regarding package dependencies [here](https://docs.racket-lang.org/pkg/metadata.html).